# multiple joins & multiplication across

Tags: mysql, sql

I asked a question earlier regarding joins and now I'm stuck once again.

Here is what the db looks like:

#### Book

```
Book_code (unique)
Price 
book_title
publisher_code
book_type
```

#### Branch

```
Branch_num (unique)
Branch_name (unique)
branch_location
num_employees
```

#### Inventory

```
Branch_number
Book_code
On_hand ( the quantity of books )
```

now the question is: List branches that have the total inventory amount (i.e., sum of on_hand times price) greater than 300.

I know I have to make use of all the tables. I have started out coding the following:

```
SELECT br.branch_name, br.branch_num, i.on_hand , b.book_code, b.price
FROM book b, inventory i, branch br
WHERE br.branch_num = i.branch_num
and b.book_code = i.book_code;
```

but im stuck after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT br.branch_name, br.branch_num, SUM(i.on_hand * b.price) as on_hand_price
FROM book b, inventory i, branch br
WHERE br.branch_num = i.branch_num
and b.book_code = i.book_code
GROUP by br.branch_num,br.branch_name
Having Sum(i.on_hand* b.price) > 300
ORDER BY branch_name;
```

You just missed a `GROUP`ing over branch number and name.. and finally verifying the `SUM` of on hand amount check in that group using `hAVING`.

Comment: i get the code but for some reason im not getting an answer set ;[

Comment: now it works! guess i just had to log in and out of the vm. kudos!

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT a.Branch_Name, a.Branch_Num, sum(i.on_hand * a.price) as TotalInventory
    from Book a
    inner join inventory i
    USING (Book_code)
    inner join Branch b
    ON b.Book_num = i.Book_Num
    group by 1,2 
    HAVING SUM(i.On_hand * a.price) > 300
    order by 3 desc;
```